# Ethereum Staking node without having to synchronize the entire blockchain

Tags: staking

I'm trying to set up an Ethereum staking node on the Goerli testnet. My goal is to understand how it works. Is it possible to avoid downloading the entire Ethereum blockchain to set up a staking node? If yes, how?